# \Titleofalg with algorithm2e package

Tags: algorithm2e

The following code gives me an error and I am not sure why:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{default}
% typesetting of algorithms
\usepackage[vlined,linesnumbered]{algorithm2e}
\SetArgSty{textnormal}
\SetCommentSty{textnormal}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}%{ % Implementation of pin() (((

  \frametitle{Implementation of \texttt{pin\,()}}

  \begin{function}[H]
    \Titleofalgo{ \texttt{pin($\mathit{pageno}$)}}
    \eIf
      {buffer pool already contains $\mathit{pageno}$}
      {$\texttt{pinCount\,(\(\mathit{pageno}\))} \leftarrow
           \texttt{pinCount\,(\(\mathit{pageno}\))} + 1$ \;
       \Return{address of frame holding $\mathit{pageno}$ \;}}
      {select a victim frame $v$ using the replacement policy \;
       \If{$\texttt{dirty\,(\(v\))}$}
          {write $v$ to disk \;}
       read page $\mathit{pageno}$ from disk into frame $v$ \;
       $\texttt{pinCount\,(\(\mathit{pageno}\))} \leftarrow 1$ \;
       $\texttt{dirty\,(\(\mathit{pageno}\))} \leftarrow \text{false}$ \;
       \Return{address of frame $v$} \;
      }
 \end{function}
\end{frame} 

\end{document}
```

The error message I get is

```
./test.tex:31: Undefined control sequence.
\beamer@doifinframe ...{function}[H] \Titleofalgo 
                                                  { \texttt {pin($\mathit {p...
l.31 \end{frame}
```

and I cannot figure out why. What am I missing please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Beware of the proper spelling; it's `\TitleOfAlgo` (T, O, A upper case) and not `\Titleofalgo`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{default}
% typesetting of algorithms
\usepackage[vlined,linesnumbered]{algorithm2e}
\SetArgSty{textnormal}
\SetCommentSty{textnormal}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}%{ % Implementation of pin() (((

  \frametitle{Implementation of \texttt{pin\,()}}

  \begin{function}[H]
    \TitleOfAlgo{\texttt{pin($\mathit{pageno}$)}}
    \eIf
      {buffer pool already contains $\mathit{pageno}$}
      {$\texttt{pinCount\,(\(\mathit{pageno}\))} \leftarrow
           \texttt{pinCount\,(\(\mathit{pageno}\))} + 1$ \;
       \Return{address of frame holding $\mathit{pageno}$ \;}}
      {select a victim frame $v$ using the replacement policy \;
       \If{$\texttt{dirty\,(\(v\))}$}
          {write $v$ to disk \;}
       read page $\mathit{pageno}$ from disk into frame $v$ \;
       $\texttt{pinCount\,(\(\mathit{pageno}\))} \leftarrow 1$ \;
       $\texttt{dirty\,(\(\mathit{pageno}\))} \leftarrow \text{false}$ \;
       \Return{address of frame $v$} \;
      }
 \end{function}
\end{frame} 

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

I also suppressed an spurious blank space in the title.

Comment: Thank you Gonzalo and Bernard. I copied this from a slide deck that I received from a colleague and the error occurred while trying to compile his slide deck. I tried a few things, but never thought that his spelling would be wrong. Many thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You forgot TeX is case-sensitive – the command is `\TitleOfAlgo`, and there is no `default` package – only a `default theme` for beamer:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{default}
% typesetting of algorithms
\usepackage[vlined,linesnumbered]{algorithm2e}
\SetArgSty{textnormal}
\SetCommentSty{textnormal}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}%{ % Implementation of pin() (((

  \frametitle{Implementation of \texttt{pin\,()}}

  \begin{function}[H]
    \TitleOfAlgo{ \texttt{pin($\mathit{pageno}$)}}
    \eIf
      {buffer pool already contains $\mathit{pageno}$}
      {$\texttt{pinCount\,(\(\mathit{pageno}\))} \leftarrow
           \texttt{pinCount\,(\(\mathit{pageno}\))} + 1$ \;
       \Return{address of frame holding $\mathit{pageno}$ \;}}
      {select a victim frame $v$ using the replacement policy \;
       \If{$\texttt{dirty\,(\(v\))}$}
          {write $v$ to disk \;}
       read page $\mathit{pageno}$ from disk into frame $v$ \;
       $\texttt{pinCount\,(\(\mathit{pageno}\))} \leftarrow 1$ \;
       $\texttt{dirty\,(\(\mathit{pageno}\))} \leftarrow \text{false}$ \;
       \Return{address of frame $v$} \;
      }
 \end{function}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]